# Django 1.6 adding custom fields to the User model

Tags: python, django

I've got the following

***profile/models.py***

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    university = models.CharField(max_length=200, choices=UNIVERSITY, null=True)
```

***profile/views.py***

```
class UserForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ('username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'university')
```

I've run south and the database is up to date but I still get this error

```
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Unknown field(s) (first_name, username, email, last_name) specified for UserProfile
```

I'm guessing it's something to do with the way the tables are linked. In my UserProfile table I have **id, user_id, and university** columns with appropriate data in them.

Comment: maybe fields=(user.username,user.first_name,user.last_name,user.email,'university')

Comment: Tried that already - same error.

Comment: You are not adding custom fields to the user model here. You have a separate UserProfile model. That is *not* the recommended thing to do since 1.5. You should extend the AbstractUser class instead.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-user. That's for 1.6 and it says to do so. UserProfile is just a naming convention I used as it is a user's profile I want to access.

Comment: Well I've changed it anyway now to extend the AbstractBaseUser and still get the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this in the end by [substituting a custom User model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model). This allowed me to set all the user fields in one table called profiles_users and have extra fields.

There is some customisation to set up but I found this approach much more fluid than extending the User base class, personally.

Answer (score 0):

A `ModelForm` can only generate form fields for a single model, in this case `UserProfile`. The `fields` attribute in your meta class specifies which form fields to display. In this case, the fields `first_name`, `username`, `email` and `last_name` are not defined. You'll have to manually define them on your form, and alter the save method to save the `User` object:

```
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    username = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = forms.EmailField()
    ...

    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ('username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'university')

    def save(self, commit=True):
        # save user and profile
```

Answer (score 0):

A `ModelForm` can only generate fields for a single model (the one specified in the `Meta` class)

The Django way to have a form with fields for related models is an Inline formset:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#inline-formsets

eg

```
# forms.py
UserProfileFormSet = inlineformset_factory(User, UserProfile, max_num=1)

# views.py
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render_to_response
from .forms import UserProfileFormSet

def myview(request, user_id):
    user = get_object_or_404(User, pk=user_id)
    formset = UserProfileFormSet(request.POST or None, instance=user)
    if formset.is_valid():
        formset.save()
        # ...redirect here
    return render_to_response("my_template.html", {
        "formset": formset,
    })
```

Comment: This partially works. I have the university displaying on the my-profile page but the rest of the standard user fields are missing.

Comment: are you sure your `User` model has those fields? are you rendering `formset.as_p` in the template?

Comment: Yes the specified fields are in the `User` model and I'm rendering it in the template with bootstrap using `formset|bootstrap`. I solved this through a custom User model explained in my own answer.